# Why can't I use "create schema" in a begin/end block in SQL Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I generated a script which creates all users and schemas for this database and when I wrap the CREATE statements with an IF EXISTS check I find that it does not allow the CREATE SCHEMA call to run in the BEGIN/END block. It complains that it is invalid syntax. Yet I can run the command on it's own. A sample of the code is below. I am using SQL Server 2008 and Management Studio R2. Why is this invalid syntax?

```
--DROP SCHEMA [acme]

IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = 'acme')) 
BEGIN
    CREATE SCHEMA [acme] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
END
```

Comment: I've cleared that I can wrap the CREATE SCHEMA statement with EXECUTE to allow the statement to work. See EXECUTE('CREATE SCHEMA [acme] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]') http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189462.aspx

Comment: This is horseshit...surely we're not all cluttering our code with pointless EXEC statements?

Comment: If only `create schema` supported the `if exists` predicate... ;_;

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Schema creations must be the only statement in a batch. One way to get around it is like so:

```
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = 'acme')) 
BEGIN
    EXEC ('CREATE SCHEMA [acme] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]')
END
```

Answer (score 50):

Here is an even simpler solution (simpler check):

```
IF (SCHEMA_ID('acme') IS NULL) 
BEGIN
    EXEC ('CREATE SCHEMA [acme] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]')
END
```

Answer (score 11):

It needs to be in its own batch. You can wrap it in `EXEC('')`

```
EXEC('CREATE SCHEMA [acme] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]')
```

I believe the reason for the requirement is something to do with an older version of the `CREATE SCHEMA` syntax introduced  in version 6.5 ([at least that's what it says here](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html#newschcommands)).

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes (always) you're not allowed to use Dynamic SQL, so using `EXEC` is not the best approach. Using `GO` statement can do things better:

```
USE [MyDB]
GO

IF (SCHEMA_ID('MySchema') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    DROP SCHEMA [MySchema];
END

GO

CREATE SCHEMA [MySchema] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]

GO
```

Comment: If you already have tables for that schema then you cannot drop it without dropping the tables (or other object).

Answer (score 5):

`CREATE SCHEMA` must be in it's own batch, so embed it inside an `EXEC` and you should be OK.

```
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = 'acme')) 
BEGIN
    EXEC ('CREATE SCHEMA [acme] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]')
END
```