# Create Schema MS SQL won't work in IF-Statement

Tags: sql-server

Why does this give an error:

```
IF(SCHEMA_ID('AM') IS NULL)
BEGIN
    CREATE SCHEMA AM
    GO
END
```

This works:

```
IF(SCHEMA_ID('AM') IS NULL)
BEGIN
    Print 'null'
END
```

And the create schema statement on one row works, but not the create schema inside the if-statement.
So they both work individually, but not together.

Comment: The `GO` needs to go at the very end of the script, not in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CREATE SCHEMA` is one of these statements that must be alone in batch.
Try:

```
IF (SCHEMA_ID('AM') IS NULL) 
BEGIN
    EXEC ('CREATE SCHEMA [AM]')
END
```

For more info see : [Why can't I use "create schema" in a begin/end block in SQL Management Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748056/why-cant-i-use-create-schema-in-a-begin-end-block-in-sql-management-studio)