# T-SQL - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Trigger' and Expecting EXTERNAL

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have this (simplified) t-sql script:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory] WHERE [MigrationId] = N'20191025090642_DbName_v6'
)
BEGIN
    CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[CREATEID] ON [dbo].[LibNumber]
    INSTEAD OF INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT 1
        -- Some other stuff...
    END 
END;
GO
```

I get:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TRIGGER'.
```

And

```
Incorrect syntax near 'Begin'. Expecting EXTERNAL
```

Why am I wrong? Looks like it is the IF NOT EXISTS statement. Am I right?

Comment: Creating a `TRIGGER` needs to be in its own batch.

Comment: Although you are trying to create a trigger, not a schema, [this answer should help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5748056/1048425). Alternatively you could reverse your logic. If the trigger exists, drop it. Then in a new batch have your create trigger script.

Comment: Seems extremely odd to create a trigger on one table only if there is a row with a certain value in another table.

Comment: @SeanLange That is a very good point. @nwdom ignore my comment about reversing the logic. I read the `IF NOT EXISTS` and assumed it would be checking for the existence of the trigger before creating it, not a row in a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, You can't handle Some DDL scripts (Create, Alter, Drop) in DML workflow.

Using Dynamic SQL is the only way to handle it.

Here it is a sample :

```
Declare @SQL as nvarchar(max)
Set @SQL = 
N'CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[CREATEID] ON [dbo].[LibNumber]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 1
    -- Some other stuff...
END'

IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory] WHERE [MigrationId] = N'20191025090642_DbName_v6'
)
BEGIN
    Exec (@SQL)
END;
GO
```

Comment: @Larnu; You are looking after all of my post and tell me about something off the topic? My man, its the solution to execute the dynamic query.

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using EXEC() instead of sp_executesql](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql)

Comment: Not sure why my comment was deleted.  But no, it's not off topic when this is a solution that promotes SQL injection. The OP should be aware when they are being given code that promotes security issues. [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the T-SQL in question is for handling triggers in the Entity Framework migrations. So who wants to inject SQL? EF? Administrator?

Comment: *"So who wants to inject SQL?"* *You* are, @XAMT: `'...ProductID = '+ @Pid`. You are *injecting* the value of `@Pid`.

Comment: If you change your answer to not inject the values, then I'm happy to upvote this; however as it stands it is a **dangerous** answer. If you're not willing to learn from that, then you are also stating that you are happy to write insecure code. That is something you *need* to stop doing.

Comment: @Larnu; I'm convinced. Thanks for the info.

Comment: The correct approach should be to parametrise the value, @XAMT . In the articles linked above they both show how you can use `sp_executesql` to parametrise a dynamic statement. I suggest having a read, Aaron Bertrand writes some great articles and gives some brilliant advice in your "Bad Habits" series.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, they helped me a lot. XAMT, could I put the 'Set @SQL ='  statement inside the 'BEGIN' block just before the 'Exec' statement?

Comment: @nwdom, yes you can. Please don't forget to mark as an accepted answer if your problem solved.